# Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit PageTest class and authenticating once using StorageState

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, nunit, playwright

I am looking to use Playwright's StorageState class to avoid each test file requiring to login. I have created a LoginTest class as below to store the StorageState. I am also using POM and utilizing Playwright's NUnit PageTest class. This class does create a json file, which I assume is correct.

```
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
[TestFixture]
public class LoginTests : PageTest 
{
private readonly LaunchPage _launchPage;
private readonly LoginPopUpPage _loginPopUpPage;

//[OneTimeSetUp]
[SetUp]
public async Task Setup()
{
    var url = TestContext.Parameters["webAppUrl"];
    await Page.GotoAsync(url);

    LaunchPage _launchPage = new LaunchPage(Page);
    LoginPopUpPage _loginPopUpPage = new LoginPopUpPage(Page);
    var username = TestContext.Parameters["webAppUserName"];
    var password = TestContext.Parameters["webAppPassword"];

    _loginPopUpPage.Page = await _launchPage.ClickLogin();
    await _loginPopUpPage.EnterEmail(username);
    await _loginPopUpPage.EnterUsername(username);
    await _loginPopUpPage.EnterPassword(password);
    var storageState = await Page.Context.StorageStateAsync(new()
    {
        Path = "state.json"
    });
}
```

I then have several other tests in separate files. I'm not sure how to code this to avoid duplicating code. I'm new to both Playwright and C#, excuse my terrible code.

```
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]
[TestFixture]
public class ReportTests : PageTest
{
private readonly DashboardPage _dashboardPage; //create instance of POM
private readonly ReportPage _reportPage; //create instance of POM

public ReportTests() //not sure if this is correct
{
    DashboardPage _dashboardPage = new DashboardPage(Page);
    ReportPage _reportPage = new ReportPage(Page);
}

[SetUp]
public async Task SetUp()
{
    var url = TestContext.Parameters["webAppUrl"];
    var context = await Browser.NewContextAsync(new()
    {
        StorageStatePath = "state.json"
    });
    var Page = await context.NewPageAsync();
    await Page.GotoAsync(url);
}

[Test]
public async Task CreateReport()
{        
    await _dashboardPage.SelectReportsMenu();
//some more code
}
```

Is [SetUp] correct for each test file to access the saved authentication state? Also, when I navigate to the new page and url, it loads the launch screen containing a Login button - do I then have to click login again or should it load the page and bypass the login? The web app uses Azure B2C authentication. Thank you